# Send information of user from users.js to app.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating a multiplayer game where I have login system as well. So I have my app.js and users.js. In users.js data about user is stored and I want send that information to my app.js.

My **app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/loginapp');
var db = mongoose.connection;

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

// Init App
var app = express();
var server = require("http").Server(app);
 var io = require("socket.io")(server);

// View Engine
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout:'layout'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

// BodyParser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

// Set Static Folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Express Session
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}));

// Passport init
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Express Validator
app.use(expressValidator({
  errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
      var namespace = param.split('.')
      , root    = namespace.shift()
      , formParam = root;

    while(namespace.length) {
      formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
    }
    return {
      param : formParam,
      msg   : msg,
      value : value
    };
  }
}));

// Connect Flash
app.use(flash());

// Global Vars
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
  res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
  res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
  res.locals.user = req.user || null;
  next();
});

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", this.address().port, app.settings.env);
});
```

My **users.js**

```
var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    var passport = require('passport');
    var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

    var User = require('../models/users');

    // Register
    router.get('/register', function(req, res){
        res.render('register');
    });

    // Login
    router.get('/login', function(req, res){
        res.render('login');
    });

    //Register User
    router.post('/register', function(req, res){
        var name = req.body.name;
        var email = req.body.email;
        var username = req.body.username;
        var password = req.body.password;
        var password2 = req.body.password2;

    // Validation
        req.checkBody('name', 'Name is required').notEmpty();
        req.checkBody('email', 'Email is required').notEmpty();
        req.checkBody('email', 'Email is not valid').isEmail();
        req.checkBody('username', 'Username is required').notEmpty();
        req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();
        req.checkBody('password2', 'Passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);


        var errors = req.validationErrors();

        if(errors)
        {
            res.render('register',{
                errors:errors
            });

        } else 
        {
            var newUser = new User({
                name: name,
                email:email,
                username: username,
                password: password
            });

            User.createUser(newUser, function(err, user){
                if(err) throw err;
                console.log(user);
            });

            req.flash('success_msg', 'You are registered and can now login');

            res.redirect('/users/login');
        }
    });

    passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
      function(username, password, done) {
       User.getUserByUsername(username, function(err, user){
        if(err) throw err;
        if(!user){
            return done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown User'});
        }

        User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch){
            if(err) throw err;
            if(isMatch){
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid password'});
            }
        });
       });
      }));

    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
      done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
      User.getUserById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
      });
    });

    router.post('/login',
      passport.authenticate('local', {successRedirect:'/', failureRedirect:'/users/login',failureFlash: true}),
      function(req, res) {
        res.redirect('/');
      });       

    router.get('/logout', function(req, res){
        req.logout();

        req.flash('success_msg', 'You are logged out');

        res.redirect('/users/login');
    });


    module.exports = router;
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

**UPDATE:**
   **index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

   // Get Homepage
   router.get('/', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
   res.render('index');
 });

  function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next){
     if(req.isAuthenticated()){
      return next();
     } else {
        //req.flash('error_msg','You are not logged in');
        res.redirect('/users/login');
     }
  }

 module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already 'loading' your users into your app, assuming that `users.js` is actually at `/routes/users.js`.  The line `var users = require('./routes/users')` in app.js is importing your export of the user routes.

You are then using these routes for your application for any path whose first argument is `/users` by `app.use('/users',users)`.

If you are having a particular issue with getting user data in or out of your application, you will need to edit your question to provide more detail.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot that. However, I know how module.exports work, but not in this case. I just want to console log the newUser's name property in my app.js. I added index.js file in my original post, hope that will help. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: What you'd want to do @Ruben is put your `console.log()` statement in your `users.js` file.  The user object isn't currently being passed to the app.js file and doesn't need to be.  You could have written all of this in one JavaScript file if you wanted to.  By exporting/importing you're simply modularizing your code (which is a good thing).  Express will call the callback function for whatever route is requested and `users.js` is the proper place to log anything to your console.

Comment: Thanks for your respond, @metame. The problem is that when I `console.log(User.getUserByUsername("username"))` in my **users.js** it just writes undefined. Also I want to export it to my app.js so that I can emit it to my client side in order to display it there.If needed I can provide you with my full code. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: `User.getUserByUsername()` is an async function provided by passport.  You would need to do a `console.log(user.username)` within the callback of the `getUserByUsername` function.

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot, @metame! I just would like to ask you for another favor. Can you please tell me how to send that to my app.js?

Comment: I found how to do that, @metame, however there is one error. Could you please go to this link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37471867/cant-access-req-users-properties. Thank you