# can't access req.user's properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am creating a multiplayer game with login system. In my app.js I have

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
  res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
  res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
  res.locals.user = req.user || null;

  next();
});
```

Using which I can access my user. When I write there  `console.log(req.user);` it works fine.It displays my user's properties. For example:

```
{ __v: 0,
  password: '$2a$10$fHVFeChN4xo67ioWMDfix.VOFLAbNu33xAoRb09b9QRwnmOJ389/O',
  username: 'a',
  email: 'example@gmail.com',
  name: 'a',
  _id: 5744c2b7835f90cc05d27ee5 }
```

However, when I write `console.log(req.user.username);` it displays error:

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined.**

I'll be grateful for any help. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution. I just needed to put my module.exports in my app.js.

Comment: Can you expand on this? I'm having the same issue